# Pass Python list to AngularJS module

Tags: python, angularjs, django, module

I am currently creating a search box which will give suggested list taken from database but I am having trouble getting the correct syntax in passing `Python` list to `AngularJS` module.

This is my `Python` List:

```
TaskNameList =  [{'id':'1','name':'Alabama'},{'id':'2','name': 'Alaska'}]
```

I think I wasn't able to get the correct syntax here where the TaskNameList is from `views.py`:

```
$scope.states = {{ TaskNameList }};
```

And this is my complete template codes:

`index.html`:

```
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script>
      angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('TypeaheadCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.selected = undefined;
  $scope.states = {{ TaskNameList }};
  // Any function returning a promise object can be used to load values asynchronously
  $scope.getLocation = function(val) {
    return $http.get('', {
      params: {
        sensor: false
      }
    }).then(function(response){
      return response.data.results.map(function(item){
        return item.formatted_address;
      });
    });
  };

});
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

<div class='container-fluid' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">

    <h4>Static arrays</h4>
    <input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state as state.name for state in states | filter:{name:$viewValue} | limitTo:8" class="form-control">

   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Django varibles in javascript access as "{{ TaskNameList }}". Can you show `console.log("{{ TaskNameList }}")` ?

Answer (score 1):

A better option is to convert the array to json, like so:

```
import json
TaskNameListJson = json.dumps(TaskNameList)
```

and in your template (using safe filter for HTML escaping):

```
{{ TaskNameListJson|safe }}
```

BTW, you should use the verbatim tags, to avoid conflicts with angular templating syntax: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim